# Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large. CUSUM plot

Tags: r

Estoy haciendo un modelo econométrico y estoy usando esta función `"ardlBound(data=serie,formula=formula1,case=3,autoOrder=FALSE,max.p=8,max.q=8,ic=c("AIC"),ECM=TRUE,stability=TRUE)"` en R. Cuando la aplico, no me aparecen los gráficos de `CUSUM` ni de `CUSUM Q` y me aparece esto:

> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large.

Ya utilicé esto `par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))`, y aún así siguen sin aparecerme las gráficas.
¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este es un error clásico de la función base `plot()` en Rstudio, cuando, básicamente es demasiada la información para poder ser visualizada en la "superficie" asignada en el panel de gráficos.

Se puede reproducir el problema con cualquier gráfico, por ejemplo `plot(1:10)`, si ajustamos los paneles, para ir achicando la superficie del panel de gráficos, tarde o temprano tendremos este error. Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las soluciones:

- Ajustar el tamaño del panel al máximo posible ante de ejecutar el gráfico (no funciona hacer zoom)
- Achicar los márgenes al mínimo: `par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))`
- No visualizar el gráfico, sino salvarlo directamente a un archivo:

  ```
    png("plot.png")
    plot(1:10)
    dev.off()
  ```